# C++ linked list user input out of bound validation causes program to end

Tags: c++, validation, linked-list

I have a delete node based on position function and I am trying to do validation with the logic that the user input will repeat itself whenever the user's input is larger than the linked list size or in other words out of bound.

I declared `int size` and it'll increment itself whenever a new node is created, vice versa for remove node. Here is my remove node function:

```
    void delete_position(int pos) //delete node with given position
    {
        node *current=new node;
        node *previous=new node;
        current=head;

        if(head==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"You haven't ordered any cake(s)"<<endl;
        }

        for(int i=1;i<pos;i++)
        {
            previous=current;
            current=current->next;
        }
        previous->next=current->next;

        if(pos == 1){
            node *temp=new node;
            temp=head;
            head=head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        size--;
    }
```

Here is my validation, I used a do while loop to check the user's input, so whenever the input is larger than the size, it'll loop the user input once again. The problem is, say there are only 2 nodes in my list and I enter 4, the program jumps to the next line and ends.

```
cout<<"====destroy node===="<<endl;
cout<<"Which cake would you like to destroy?"<<endl;

do{

cin>>destroy_input;

}while(destroy_input > size);

list.delete_position(destroy_input);
```

Here is my code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vfuRYMLk

**Re-polished my code :** works for me, feel free to edit if anything is missing or wrong, i've gotten rid of the memory leak for this function, pretty new to this topic, sorry my previous mistakes.

```
void delete_position(int pos) //delete node with given position
        {
            node *current = head;
            if(size == 1){
                head=NULL;
                tail=NULL;
            }
            else{
                if(pos == 1){
                    head = head->next;
                }else{
                    node *previous = NULL;
                    for(int i=1; i<pos; i++){
                        previous = current;
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    if(current == tail){
                        previous->next =NULL;
                        tail = previous;
                    }else{
                        previous->next = current->next;
                    }
                }
                delete current;
                size--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger yet to step through your code?

Comment: Not the cause, but deleting a node should not create any new nodes - you're leaking memory. (`new` is not for creating pointers, it's for creating objects.)

Comment: First debugging step: have you verified that `size` really *is* 2, or are you simpy assuming that it is because you added two elements?

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah I’ve verified them, after adding three nodes I print out “size” variable and it tells me that I have three nodes, delete one and it shows two.

Comment: _The problem is, say there are only 2 nodes in my list and I enter 4, the program jumps to the next line and ends._ Concerning this: Have a closer look at your loop `for(int i=1;i<pos;i++)`. The condition is `i < pos` but it doesn't check whether end of list is reached before `i < pos` fails. That let you step over `next` of last node and afterwards probably the crash happens due to `nullptr` access. (You should confirm my assumption with step-wise debugging.)

Comment: @Scheff so I'm supposed to do a checking in my for loop too see if `i` has already reached end of the list, still new to linked list so I'm not sure how i should approach this method.

Comment: The simplest way would be to just extend your condition: `for (int i = 1; i < pos && current; ++i)`. Of course, you have to bail out afterwards if the loop stopped due to second part of condition: `if (!current) return; // node with index not existing`

Comment: @mrtammy Do I understand correctly that you are wondering why your code jumps out of the while loop when it should stay in because the condition is true?

Comment: @Ashkan yeah that's what i'm wondering, shouldn't my while loop be correct and it should continue looping if `destroy_input` is larger than `size`. edit: wondering why my while loop is functioning as intended.

Comment: Obvious question but did you actually check what you get in destroy_input? Also why don't you have validation checks on the input? Is this part of the code only going to be used by you?

Comment: Please, consider that the counting of index `i` is not the only thing your loop does. It also "moves" `current` from node to node with `current=current->next;`. If `pos` is greater than number of nodes, `current->next` will be a `nullptr` just when `i == size`. Hence, in next iteration `current` is a `nullptr`. Then `current->next` is a `nullptr` access and BAM! Accessing a `nullptr` is Undefined Behavior. If you are lucky your application crashs immediately and you should start to debug. Otherwise, strange things may happen soon or later and you will wonder about it and where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few bugs in your function.

```
void delete_position(int pos) //delete node with given position
{
  node *current=new node;  // New? Why?
  node *previous=new node; // New? Why?
  current=head; // current was not deleted. Memory leak.
```

Why do you create two nodes here? You are losing your pointer first thing in this function, so you definitely have a memory leak, and then you'll lose `previous` as soon as you enter the `for`. You're leaking two `node`.

```
for(int i=1;i<pos;i++) // start at position 1, since you already have head.
{
  previous = current;
  current = current->next;
}

previous->next = current->next;
```

Note that if the position of the node to delete is 1, you never enter the `for` loop. But still, you're assigning `previous->next` to `current->next`. In your case, previous is set to a new node that has been initialized to default value. In short, a new node that is not in your list gets the value of `head->next`.

```
if(pos == 1)
{
  node *temp = new node; // create a new node again? Why?
  temp = head; // You lost your newly created memory. New memory leak here.
  head = head->next;
  delete temp;
}
size--;
```

If the condition passes, then you create a new default node. You swiftly lose the pointer to overwrite it with the pointer value of `head`. It then becomes the second node and is deleted.

Is your list 1-based? It seems that you tried to make a special case for `head` when `pos == 1`.

If it's supposed to be 0-based, a better solution would be :

```
bool delete_position(int pos) //delete node with given position
{
  node *current = head;
  node *previous = nullptr;
  bool deleted = false;

  // If your list is 1-based, though I don't see why it would be, uncomment the following line.
  // pos--;

  if((size > 0) && (pos < size))
  {
    // Search fo the node
    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
    {
      previous = current;
      current = current->next;
    }

    // Connect next node with previous node (if it's not head)
    if(previous)
    {
      previous->next = current->next;
    }

    // Remove the current node
    delete current;
    size--;

    deleted = true;
  }

  return deleted;
}
```

I haven't analyzed all your program, but I suspect that you may have a few other memory leaks floating around. Look for `new` that doesn't have a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: Full disclosure : I haven't compile that code. Hic svnt dracones. If you spot a bug, don't hesitate to tell me, or to directly edit the post.